# How to change URL after for loop iter a array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building an ajax response and facing a problem. I want to iterat over a array in JS and render an  each element with a different URL, but the URL is not changing with every element inside the array. Here's my example and code:

```
transcript_list = ['first_element_value','second_element_value']
var len = transcript_list.length

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  $(".transcript").append('<a href = /web_data/output/' + transcript_list[i] + '>' + transcript_list[i] + '</a>' + '|');
}
```

If I have two elements in the array I can get the first url as

`/web_data/output/first_element_value`

but for second url on second element I can only get the URL as

`/web_data/output/`

which missing the second_element_value at the end of the URL. Can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: What are `transcript_list` and `len`?

Comment: And what is `len`? Not strictly related (depending on the real values in the strings) but IMO HTML attribute value strings should be quoted to avoid potential issues.

Comment: Does "iter" mean "iterate over"? Please use full words.

Comment: Once the code is fixed (replace `transcript_list` with `transcript`, use `transcript.length` instead of `len`) it works fine. I have put the fixed code into an answer as a snippet; this allows people to experiment easily.

Comment: thanks for your suggest and I will try then all, and for len that my fault that i missed that i have alread writen line above : var len = transcript_list.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the code is fixed it appears to work fine:

```js
transcript = ['first_element_value','second_element_value']

for (var i = 0; i < transcript.length; i++) {
  $(".transcript").append('<a href = /web_data/output/' + transcript[i] + '>' + transcript[i] + '</a>' + '|');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transcript"></div>
```

A slightly-cleaner version might read:

```js
transcripts = ['first_element_value', 'second_element_value']

const links = transcripts
  .map(t => `<a href="/web_data/output/${t}">${t}</a>`)
  .join('&nbsp;|&nbsp;')

$(".transcript").append(links)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transcript"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, I'm gonna try this out and see if it works!